# Contributors of PRs to branches to do not appear in contributors list

Tags: github

I'm using GitHub for various F/OSS projects. When people contribute a PR to a branch (i.e. not the master), they do not appear in the contributors list after having merged the PR. This is not fair for them and it is then difficult for me to track contributions and list them.

What would be the correct way to merge PRs on a branch to have the originating user appear in the contributors list?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of features on the GitHub cover only the master branch, for example a search and statistics, so I doubt you can do anything here without implementing a custom statistics using the API.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have merged the PRs into `master` by `rebase` instead of `merge`.

Merging with a merge commit preserves the contributor's branch details.
Merging with a rebase will simply replay the contributor's commits on top of `master`.

Comment: the PR has been merged into a feature branch, not into ``master``. The merge has been done using GitHub UI. The contributor's branch details are preserved (graph > network shows that the commits have been done by the contributor). However, the contributor does not appear in the contributors list.

Comment: Oh... like @EgorZhuk said, the stats are based off the `master` branch. The contributors will be added to the graph when you merge the `feature` branch into `master`